# Comparing two text boxes for Integer value in jquery with number validation

Tags: php, jquery

I have two text box. one is From date and another is To date. i validate both text box with number. but my requirement is if i fill from date 700 than TO date accept greater than 700.
Here is my HTML

```js
$("#from").keypress(function(e) {
  //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
  if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
    //display error message
    $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow").css("color", "red");;
    return false;
  }
});
$("#to").keypress(function(e) {
  //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
  if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
    //display error message
    $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow").css("color", "red");;
    return false;
  }
});
$("#searchsubmit").click(function() {
  var to = $("#to").val();
  var from = $("#from").val();
  if (to == "" && from == "") {
    //alert('Please Provide Era Value For From And To');
    $("#response").html("Please Provide Era Value For From And To").show().fadeOut(3000).css("color", "red");
    //window.location();
  } else {
    var info = 'to=' + to + '&from=' + from; {
      if (info) {
        //alert(info);
        window.location.href = "timeline.php?from=" + from + '&to=' + to;;
      } else {
        alert('No Data Found');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<span class="info"> From </span>
<input class="erainput" name="from" id="from" type="text" placeholder="UP To 700" required />
</span>
<span class="eraform">
    <span id="errmsg"></span>
<span class="info"> To </span>
<input class="erainput" name="to" id="to" type="text" placeholder="2000" required />
</span>
<span class="eraform">
  <button type="submit" id="searchsubmit" name="submit" class="eraBtn"> Search <i class="fa fa-search"></i> </button>
</span>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. DRY (don't repeat yourself)
2. use parseInt
3. use Ajax
4. test isNaN
5. test pasting (on input)
6. use a button - please see changes to your HTML, I also added a response div
7. NEVER call anything in a form `name="submit"` it hides the form submit event
8. info will ALWAYS be true - you do not have an empty string

   ```js
   $("#from, #to").on("keypress input", function(e) {
     //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
     if (isNaN($(this).val()) || (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57))) {
       //display error message
       $(this).val("");
       $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow").css("color", "red");;
       return false;
     }
   });
   $("#searchsubmit").click(function() {
     var to = parseInt($("#to").val(), 10);
     var from = parseInt($("#from").val(), 10);
     if (to == ""    || from == "" ||
         isNaN(to)   || isNaN(from)|| // not likely possible now
         to   < from ||
         from < 700  ||
         to   > 2000 
     ) {
       $("#response").html("Please provide valid Era values for From and To").show().fadeOut(3000).css("color", "red");
     } else {
       var info = 'to=' + to + '&from=' + from;
       console.log(info);
       $("#response").load("timeline.php?from=" + from + '&to=' + to);
     }
   });
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
   <span class="info"> From </span>
   <input class="erainput" name="from" id="from" type="text" placeholder="UP To 700" required />
   </span>
   <span class="eraform">
       <span id="errmsg"></span>
   <span class="info"> To </span>
   <input class="erainput" name="to" id="to" type="text" placeholder="2000" required />
   </span>
   <span class="eraform">
     <button type="button" id="searchsubmit" class="eraBtn"> Search <i class="fa fa-search"></i> </button>
   </span>
   <div id="response"></div>
   ```

Comment: Hi Sir, sorry for my answer when I see yours I felt there is a great difference between our experience.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code and modify with your requirements.

```js
$("#searchsubmit").click(function (e) {
  var from = parseInt($("#from").val());
  var to = parseInt($("#to").val());
  if(to < from)
  {
     alert("TO value must be greater than FROM");
  }
  else 
  {
     //submit form
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="info"> From </span>
<input class="erainput" name="from" id="from" type="text" placeholder="UP To 700" required  />
</span>
<span class="eraform">
<span id="errmsg"></span>
<span class="info"> To </span>
<input class="erainput" name="to" id="to"  type="text" placeholder="2000" required  />
</span>
<span class="eraform">
<button type="submit" id="searchsubmit" name="submit" class="eraBtn"> Search <i class="fa fa-search"></i> </button>
</span>
```